# Virtual CD/DVD drive drivers not intalling in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, iso-image, virtual-drive

In my windows 7 machine, I installed Daemon tools lite so that I can mount cd/dvd iso images. But when I add a new virtual drive in Daemon Tools, the native popup of installation of driver  failer pops up in taskbar. I tried running as administrator, but no luck. Then I installed another freeware called WinCDEmu, but the same 'failed' popup comes when I try to add a virtual drive.

Is there anything fault in my registry which interrupts this driver installation?

I have install avast antivir, but I even disabled it to see whether is causes this. But results were the same.

Can anybody give me an explaination.

**Snapshots:**

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Daemon Tools.
2. Uninstall SPTD.
3. Remove legacy SPTD keys from the registry.
4. Re-install SPTD before installing Daemon Tools.
5. Install Daemon Tools Lite.

Here are the resources:

For Daemon Tools SPTD issues: http://daemonpro-help.com/?id=932
This shows how to clean up the SPTD registry keys and install SPTD by itself (without Daemon Tools)
You can download the latest SPTD by itself here: http://www.duplexsecure.com/en/downloads

Comment: This shows how to clean up the SPTD registry keys and install SPTD by itself (without Daemon Tools): http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/08/14/re-installing-daemon-tools-lite-and-sptd-on-windows-7.aspx

Comment: I didn't install SPTD in Daemon tools installtion. I only needed to Mount CD/DVD drive.